# Access an internal URL on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In my company we have some internal applications what we would like to link to in the cloud.

Do I just need to add an Embed web part in SPO and then add an iframe to a https of the local application (that can only be acccessed on our network) ?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings

Each web application can be associated with a collection of mappings between internal and public URLs. Both internal and public URLs consist of the protocol and domain portions of the full URL (for example, https://www.fabrikam.com). A public URL is what users type to access the SharePoint site, and that URL is what appears in the links on the pages. Internal URLs are in the URL requests that are sent to the SharePoint site. Many internal URLs can be associated with a single public URL in multi-server farms (for example, when a load balancer routes requests to specific IP addresses to various servers in the load-balancing cluster).

Each web application supports five collections of mappings per URL. The five collections correspond to five zones (default, intranet, extranet, Internet, and custom). When the web application receives a request for an internal URL in a particular zone, links on the pages returned to the user have the public URL for that zone. For more information, see Plan alternate access mappings for SharePoint 2013.

#### Add an internal URL

1. On the Alternate Access Mappings page, click Add Internal URLs.
2. If the mapping collection that you want to change is not specified, then choose one. In the Alternate Access Mapping Collection section, on the Alternate Access Mapping Collection menu, click Change alternate access mapping collection.
3. On the Select an Alternate Access Mapping Collection page, click a mapping collection.
4. In the Add internal URL section, in the URL protocol, host and port box, type the new internal URL (for example, https://www.fabrikam.com).
5. In the Zone list, click the zone for the internal URL.
6. Click Save.

Comment: Thanks @Ron but that article says it doesnt apply to SPO.